# Sliding options menu in tables

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, tabular

I'm having a hard time thinking how to word this one, so if it makes no sense, let me know.

I have a table that looks something like this

```
Name     | Email          | Phone
John Doe | jdoe@email.com | 555-5555
Jane Doe | jdoa@email.com | 555-5555
```

Now lets say that every listed name is a link. When you click that link, an area appears between the row you're on and the row below it. This new area pushes everything below it down. This new area can't be confined to the structure of the table's columns, can have a greater length than a regular row, but should be confined to the width of the table.

Something like this:

```
Name     | Email          | Phone
John Doe | jdoe@email.com | 555-5555
^
This is an area that was once hidden
but now is shown.
Jane Doe | jdoa@email.com | 555-5555
```

(The carrot is just my version of displaying an imaginary box for the area)

What I have so for is my table, with rows all filled and a link to a js function I've created. This function accepts an id and call jquery's slideToggle function. For every row I create, I'm also creating a second row where I set the display = none. Obviously this isn't working because that table row is now restricted to the column widths of all other rows (actually it just expands the first row).

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your table is a fixed number of cells wide, you can add a row with a single cell that spans them all using the `colspan` attribute of the cell:

```
<tr>
 <td colspan="3">
  <!-- content -->
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The slide command seems to be forcing the display to block which makes it ignore the colspan tag

Comment: In that case, you could put a `<div>` element inside the table cell and slide that up and down instead. You might have to remove excess whitespace outside the div, i.e.: `<td colspan="3"><div><!-- content --></div></td>`, and the td when the div is hidden should automatically shrink its height to 0.